# Query not executed as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a User's registration system. This is the URL called to activate a user's account:

http://../verify.php?id=40&code=fdc6604289e5a58fe1ab9dffa8e2f870

And this is the code for verify.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user = new USER();


if(empty($_GET['id']) && empty($_GET['code']))
{
    $user->redirect('index.php');
}

if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $statusY = "Y";
    $statusN = "N";

    $stmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT userID,userStatus FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uID AND tokenCode=:code LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uID"=>$id,":code"=>$code));
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        if($row['userStatus']==$statusN)
        {
            $stmt = $user->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET userStatus=:status WHERE userID=:uID");
            $stmt->bindparam(":status",$statusY);
            $stmt->bindparam(":uID",$id);
            $stmt->execute();   

            $msg = "
                   <div class='alert alert-success'>
                   <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                      <strong>WoW !</strong>  Your Account is Now Activated : <a href='index.php'>Login here</a>
                   </div>
                   ";   
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "
                   <div class='alert alert-error'>
                   <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                      <strong>sorry !</strong>  Your Account is allready Activated : <a href='index.php'>Login here</a>
                   </div>
                   ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "
               <div class='alert alert-error'>
               <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
               <strong>sorry !</strong>  No Account Found : <a href='signup.php'>Signup here</a>
               </div>
               ";
    }   
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Confirm Registration</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="login">

    <div class="container">
        <?php if(isset($msg)) { echo $msg; }
        ?>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is the record from the database:
[image]

The problem is that $_GET['id'] and $_GET['code'] are the correct values, but the page shows the option: NO ACCOUNT FOUND...

I am searching for the reason for hours, but no success.

Any help to find the source of the issue is welcome

Comment: What is the definition of the `runQuery()` method? It is not standard PDO, and it isn't clear if it just wraps `PDO::prepare()`. Have you configured PDO to throw useful exceptions and enabled error display? At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and after creating the PDO object, `$pdo_obj->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: I noticed/remember a question you posted the other day where you were mixing different MySQL APIs. I hope this isn't the case here also since your connection method is unknown. You ended up deleting the question.

Comment: debugging: I would do: `var_dump($row, $stmt->rowCount());` immediately before: `if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)`

Comment: Plus, on certain systems, `bindparam` may not work as I have seen happen before. So try `bindParam` with a capital "p".

Comment: You should not use `rowCount` with `SELECT`, see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- If there's no `bindparam()` in his class he would get an error saying that the function isn't found.

Comment: Instead of testing `rowCount()`, check whether `$row` is not empty.

Comment: @Barmar question's unclear far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Also, he's using `bindparam` in the `if` branch. The problem he's having is that he goes into the `else` branch, so he's never executing those statements.

Comment: id=40? The user should not know their ID.